# React Redux action doesn't do anything

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In Redux I created another action just copying a previous working one but it doesn't work.

The one that works:

```
export const addEntry = entry => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }

  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/db/addentry", entry, config)
      .then(results => results.data)

    try {
      await dispatch({ type: ADD_ENTRY, payload: response })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("await error", error)
    }
  }
}
```

The one that doesn't:

```
export const deleteEntry = itemId => {

  console.log("action delete 1") // step 1

  return async dispatch => {

    console.log("action delete 2") // step 2

    const response = await axios.delete(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/db/deleteitem/${itemId}`,
      itemId
    )

    try {

      console.log("action delete 3") // step 3

      await dispatch({ type: DELETE_ENTRY, payload: response })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("await error", error)
    }
  }
}
```

If I log it step by step it stops after the first log

It doens't do anything. The same function `addEntry` works perfectly. Any idea?

Comment: It seems you have to delete the entry with itemId. And you are using `axios.post`, I would suggest you use `axios.delete`. Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369563/delete-request-with-axios-react

Comment: Is it being dispatched? Can you dispatch something like `dispatch({type:'begin delete'})` before anything asynchronous? Is a request made? In there browser there is a thing called dev tools, that has a network tab where you can see network activity and if installed there is a redux tab (redux dev tools) that can be very helpful when posting questions on SO that are of a better quality than `it doesn't work` or `it does nothing`

Comment: it was already .delete but .post is just a try

Comment: @MarcoDisco It's likely you are not dispatching the action from your component, if you use react redux connect you call `props. deleteEntry(id)` from your component or `const dispatch = useDispatch();dispatch(deleteEntry(id))` if you use the hook.

Comment: Yes! Was that! I "just" forgot `dispatch` from where I call it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the ItemId, using `axios.delete` instead of `axios.post`

You also have to put your DELETE_ENTRY like `'DELETE_ENTRY'` or else your reducer won't understand it

Comment: No you have to put it between brackets to work (```''```)because in your reducers it s like : ```case 'DELETE_ENTRY':```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the first log comes through, is because that is part of the action creator. Normally, an action creator returns an object in the shape of `{ type: <type>, payload: <payload> }`, but in this case, it returns a new function, which is called a "thunk".

How does this action get dispatched?

In order for this to work, you have to include the redux-thunk middleware, which if it receives a function through `dispatch(...)`, executes that function.

Read up about [thunks here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @HMR I just forgot to `dispatch(deleteEntry(item.itemId))` when I call the action